# Qt и ip camera. Возможные пути решения

Tags: c++, qt, ip, видео

Подскажите возможные пути решения с qt, то есть с выводом в в виджет. Камера так же имеет возможности управления зумом, просто вывести данные с помощью vlc либы не подойдет. Буду рад каждому предложения.

Comment: QCamera https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcamera.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IP** камера - нетривиальная задача, нужно [снифить трафик](https://www.wireshark.org/) и попытаться провести реверс-инжиниринг API. Учитывайте, что подобное решение не будет универсальным и сработает только с конкретной моделью ip-камеры конкретного производителя конкретной прошивки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Универсальным решением является применение **ВЕБ** камеры в сочетании с библиотекой OpenCV, так как она реализует [абстракцию](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html) для захвата видео. Данный пример написан на python, но не составит труда переписать его на C++

```
import cv2

def show_webcam(mirror=False):
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        ret_val, img = cam.read()
        if mirror: 
            img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
        cv2.imshow('my webcam', img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27: 
            break  # esc to quit
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def main():
    show_webcam(mirror=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Для вывода видео с камеры можно покадрово транслировать Mat в QPixmap, приводя его к `unsigned char*` массиву, как сделано [тут](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/qt-dxgi-screenshot).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QDialog *dialog = new QDialog();
    QLabel *label = new QLabel(dialog);

    FrameBroadcast *cast = new FrameBroadcast();
    QObject::connect(cast, &FrameBroadcast::frameCaptured, [=](const QSharedPointer<Frame> &frame) {

        int w = static_cast<int>(frame.data()->width);
        int h = static_cast<int>(frame.data()->height);

        QImage img(frame.data()->buffer,w,h,QImage::Format_RGBA8888);
        label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
        label->resize(w,h);

        qDebug() << "Update";
    });
    cast->startCapture();

    dialog->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```